# Is there a way for jasper report/ireport to query data from multiple flat file and display them on report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, business-intelligence

i try search through this and come up with no result,it look like jasper report let you pass only one csv/flat file as its datasource.Is there a way to supply it with multiple flat file and query them like normal db table? I don't want to keep those data in db first because there are ton of them and store those data in db look unnecessary

thx for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggestion that you'd have to write your own data source tat was capable of reading from the required files.

Alternatively, you read all the data in yourself & pass into jasper as a `List`

Comment: Actually that's what i try to find , now i currently found out that hsqldb can read csv file and process them by using db query syntax so i keep diging it now, thx for your answer though :)

Comment: Actually that sounds really interesting, hoe it pans out